# How parse json array of object inside autcomplete c# mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I have an auto complete method.

```
$("#txtSearch").autocomplete({

                  source: function (request, response) {
                      $.ajax({
                          url: "/Home/Getsrchresult",
                          type: "POST",
                          dataType: "json",
                          data: { term: request.term, location: $('#location').val() },
                          success: function (data) {
                              response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                  return {


                                   label: item.srchresult, value: item.srchresult
                                    };
                              }))

                          }
                      })
                  }
              });
```

my controller passes multidimension array.How to place all data inside autocmplete textbox

**controller**

```
                var fd2 = (from r in db.Restaurants
                       where r.restname.ToLower().Contains(term.ToLower())
                       orderby r.state == location descending
                       select new { searchresult = r.restname ,place=r.place


                       }).Take(10);
  return Json(fd2, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Response is like this

```
[{"srchresult":"foodtakeaway","place":"karnataka"},{"srchresult":"ssdf","place":"dfsaf"}]
```

Comment: It is an array of objects, not multidimension array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
$("#txtSearch").autocomplete({
     source: function (request, response) {                  
               $.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/Getsrchresult",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",      
                    data: { term: request.term,location:$('#location').val() },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {                   
                            return { label: item.place, value: item.place };
                        }))
                    }
                })
            }  
});
```

Assuming you are returning JSON like this

```
[
    {
        "srchresult": "foodtakeaway",
        "place": "karnataka"
    },
    {
        "srchresult": "ssdf",
        "place": "dfsaf"
    }
]
```

I have used `item.place` for label and value property, you may replace it with `item.srchresult` as needed.

***Suggestion :*** Use MVC Helper methods(`Url.Action`) to generate the url to your action methods, instead of hardcoding

Comment: i have 2 items place and srchresult

Comment: This will work as long as you return n number of items with the JSON structure you mentioned.

Comment: can i retrieve both srchresult and place in  txtsearch.simultaneously

Comment: but i am getting location from javascript.so i cant send javascript variabled in url.Action

Comment: this is not the answer i required.pls understand my situation

Comment: @user3300195 You want to show a string with srchresult and place name ? Yes, just do a string concatenation inside the `$.map` part.